# problem with pause and <beamer:1>

Tags: beamer, pause

I am using beamer to make presentations. I use

```
\begin{frame}<beamer:1>[plain] ...
```

to show this slide and I change it to

```
\begin{frame}<beamer:0>[plain] ...
```

if I want to omit this slide.

The problem is that `\pause` does not work inside `\begin{frame}<beamer:1>[plain]`.

Comment: Welcome! Can you provide a complete minimal example we can compile?

Answer (score 1):

When you pass `<beamer:1>` it tells Beamer to include exactly the slide 1, and only that slide, from the frame when in the relevant mode. If you want it to include *all* slides from the frame, just say you want slides 1 and later.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<beamer:1->
  Some stuff
  \pause
  Further points about the first lot of stuff
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}<beamer:0>
  Some other stuff
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The overlay specification `1` says just slide 1. `1-` says slides 1 onwards:

[image: 1 and later]